# Malformed communication package on mysql if using execute istead of query with ST_GeomFromGeoJSON

Tags: mysql, node.js, location

I am currently facing the error

```
{
  "message": "Malformed communication packet.",
  "code":"ER_MALFORMED_PACKET","errno":1835,"sqlState":"HY000","sqlMessage":"Malformed communication packet."
}
```

if I replace .query by .execute in

```
let query = 'INSERT INTO table (_id, location,size) ' +
        'VALUES (UUID_TO_BIN(?,1), ST_GeomFromGeoJSON( \'{"type":"Point","coordinates":[ ? , ? ]}\'),?)'
      res = await mysql.execute(query, [id, location.longitude, location.latitude, size])
```

Since this query is called many times I tried using execute instead of query. I allready figured out that:

```
let query = 'INSERT INTO table (_id, location,size) ' +
        'VALUES (UUID_TO_BIN(?,1), ST_GeomFromGeoJSON( \'{"type":"Point","coordinates":[ 10,50 ]}\'),?)'
      res = await mysql.execute(query, [id, size])
```

works fine.
Is there a way to use execute ?

I am using: 
mysql2 (nodejsClient): 2.1.0 
mysql: 8.0.19

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I saw same error and changed to query() so I caught a silly problem with a missing parameter, fixed and rolled back to execute. ^^